# What is the easiest way to inject a script in to someone else's domain?

Tags: javascript

For example if I'm on www.facebook.com and I want to inject a script to analyze their DOM?  One way would be to open up the console and than use something like

```
document.createElement('script');
```

and then set the src attribute, etc.

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: @duffymo: In the console?

Comment: Define "best" - do you want to do this frequently, or just once?

Comment: @johnnysirocco SLaks is likely referencing a comment that was subsequently deleted.

Comment: I would use Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/). You can use it to modify content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to inspect someone's DOM, it's probably easiest to use a JS console or debugger (if your browser offers it natively or as an add-on like firebug).

You could use a proxy server, like Burp or ZAP, to intercept responses from the website and inject your own JavaScript.

You could duplicate the site with a web crawler.  You should get permission first, ensure that you don't violate the Terms of Service, and make sure you have lots of space.  Then you can play with the site to your heart's content :)

As another alternative, you could use an engine like XSSshell, loading the website you want to examine in an XSSshell compromised web browser, then loading the code you want to load into XSSshell.

Or, you could set up your own DNS server that specifies a local IP address for something like foo.facebook.com, but everything else as facebook.com.  Depending upon how FB manages their site (new HTTP headers, cookie paths) you may be able to run your JavaScript from your local server, while browsing FB.

If you really, really want to write code that executes in the context of the REAL website in question, not just a copy, and you don't care about violating laws, you'll need to find a cross site scripting vulnerability.  That'd also let you load your own JavaScript into the target server's execution environment.  I don't recommend this one - at least, not if you don't legally own the target environment :)

Comment: Yes, changes to the web page will have access to the DOM of the web page.  What you type may or may not execute... I depends upon exactly what it is that you type.  For example, unload probably already executed, so trying to hook onload probably won't do anything.  On the other hand, defining a function, then setting an onmouseover trigger for a ui element likely would execute.

Comment: Should also mention that you don't need to insert code if you use a console/debugger. You can inspect the Dom directly

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend writing a browser plugin, as this is really the only way the browser allows code to just be "injected" into the page. There is a browser plugin, I think it's called "Better Facebook" or something similar, that does this, scans the DOM after the page is loaded and analyzes + modifies it (in order to make it "better")

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension

http://www.techradar.com/us/news/internet/the-beginner-s-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247

Comment: I wouldn't recommend writing a real browser plugin... a simple script for Greasemonkey should be enough and is more portable.

Comment: @kapep Good point, and one reason I included a link to Greasemonkey. Never have used it myself, but it does look pretty pwowerful.

Answer (score 2):

You should check this Firefox addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

It allows You to run your JavaScript code on websites.